# Extracting a substring of a known pattern in java

Tags: java, string, substring, extract

I am dealing with strings that contain a substring I want to extract. The substring is always of the form "USX", where US is the string "US", and X is an integer of arbitrary length.

For example, consider the following strings:

- "US21"
- "US9432"
- "US121390"
- "US7"

For the following strings, I would want to extract the text in bold.

> str1 = somerandomstuff 129 moreRand **US2** $#@# o
>
> str2 = **US231** random!@@!
>
> str3 = apples or@nges 12 **US1294**

I have searched around for a way of doing this, but was unsuccessful. Any ideas on how I might be able to solve this?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("US\\d+").matcher(str1)`.

Comment: Work through:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using regex. With the regex `(US\\d+)` you will get the group that match "US" followed by an integer of arbitrary length (minimium of 1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(US\\d+)").matcher(str1);
if (matcher.find()) {// if it matched the pattern
    String result = matcher.group(0);// the group captured by the regex
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually just finished up writing this same code when I checked back on this post. Ill mark this as "accepted" since it did work.

Answer (score 0):

If all the Strings you want are separated by spaces like above, you can use split().

for example,

```
String[] strArray1 = str1.split(" ");
for (String item : strArray1) { // Cycle through all the pieces
    if (item.startsWith("US"))
         String target = item; // Your desired String
}
```

Split() breaks a string into an array with each element being whatever was between the delimiters, which were spaces in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions (regex for short) for this kind of problems.

One source about regex I like is https://www.regular-expressions.info/